# Proper density plotting

Tags: r, plot

I have 3 columns of data. In columns data ranging from approximately 0,0727
to 10,2989.

and this is how it looks:

http://i61.tinypic.com/2uen3hz.jpg

My Code

```
MyData <- read.csv2(file="C:/Users/Sysop/Desktop/Koncentracija.csv",header=T,sep=";")
MyData

Data_1<-MyData$Sul311
Data_2<-MyData$Sul322
Data_3<-MyData$Sul333

Data_1_density<- density(Data_1,na.rm = TRUE)
Data_2_density<- density(Data_2,na.rm = TRUE)
Data_3_density<- density(Data_3,na.rm = TRUE)

xlim <- range(Data_1_density$x,Data_2_density$x,Data_3_density$x, na.rm = TRUE)
ylim <- range(Data_1_density$y, Data_2_density$y, Data_3_density$y, na.rm = TRUE)

Col_1 <- rgb(1,0,0,0.4)
Col_2 <- rgb(0,0,1,0.4)
Col_3 <- rgb(0,1,0,0.4)

plot(Data_1_density, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, xlab = 'Zn concentracion, mg/l',main = 'Distribution of data', panel.first = grid(nx = 10, ny = 10))


polygon(Data_1_density, density = -1, col = Col_1)
polygon(Data_2_density, density = -1, col = Col_2)
polygon(Data_3_density, density = -1, col = Col_3)

legend('topright',c('distribution 1 ','distribution 2','distribution 3'),cex=1.0, fill = c(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3), bty = 'n',border = NA)
```

But as we can see density plots begining from negative values, but my data does not have any negative values. One column missing one value so R shows as NA, but I use (na.rm = TRUE) to ignore NA values.
So is these density plots plotted correctly or not?

Here is my data:

`Sul311 Sul322  Sul333
1,8032    NA    2,3981
3,4949  3,1696  1,8218
0,5856  0,5577  0,0837
0,1859  1,5894  0,093
1,4686  1,45    2,9744
0,079   0,0727  0,0543
1,0317  1,0782  2,7513
0,5112  0,5484  0,9295
1,3943  1,1805  2,7513
1,1526  1,1619  2,6305
1,3013  10,2989 5,577
0,5949  0,5856  0,725
0,1766  0,2696  1,6917
0,4229  0,3309  1,1089
1,1953  0,3328  1,6787
1,4853  0,6116  1,8367
0,4443  0,3514  1,2939
0,5912  0,3309  1,2901`

Comment: Do you have some that are zero or very close? Kernel density is a smoothing estimation.

Comment: Yes there are some values ranging from 0,05 to 0,6. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

you can define the begining or the "first value" with the from argument :

```
density(x, na.rm=T, from=min(x, na.rm=T))
```

for instance

Comment: Thanks for response, but when I change lines:
Data_1_density<- density(Data_1,na.rm = TRUE)

To:

Data_1_density<- density(Data_1,na.rm = TRUE,from=min(Data_1))

I get error:
Error in density.default(Data_1, na.rm = TRUE, from = min(Data_1)) : 
  non-finite 'from'

Comment: because you should also add na.rm in the min function. I edited my previous post

Comment: Well it seems to work, but then my plot is cutted of in negative values. This is how it look:
http://i59.tinypic.com/14ngv3p.jpg

Comment: well it is normal as you do not allow anymore to estimate density for values lower than your minimum values. if you don't have negative values in your vectors your plot will be cutted of in negative values. Did I miss something?

Comment: Everything is fine, just I am newbie in R. I thought that my values should be plotted in range between min and max values.
I do not like how it cuts these negative values. Maybe there is way to hide part which is in negative, because now there is a lot of unplotted space in posityve values.